# Align in middle dynamic image inside slider with absolute position

Tags: css, centering

I have following css. I want to align image in center. But it is not working?

```
element.style {
}
.bx-wrapper .bxslider li img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
.bxslider img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="bxslider" style="width: 860%; transform: translate3d(545.5px, 0px, 0px); vertical-align: middle; display: block; height: 465px; transition-duration: 0s;">
    <li class="bxslider_imge bx-clone" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; position: relative; width: 760px;"> 
        <img alt="buk" src="/uploads/thumbs/52.jpg" data-image-original-path="/uploads/thumbs/52.jpg" title="Buk" data-image-thumb-path="/uploads/thumbs/52.jpg" data-image-id="17610" data-thumb-loaded="0"> 
    </li> 
    <li class="bxslider_imge" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; position: relative; width: 760px;"> 
        <img alt="itc" src="/uploads/thumbs/e7.jpg" data-image-original-path="/uploads/thumbs/e7.jpg" title="ITC" data-image-thumb-path="/uploads/thumbs/e7.jpg" data-image-id="17607" data-thumb-loaded="1">   
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post your HTML too please.

Comment: @j08691 - posted html thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To vertical align to middle, I like to use:

```
.elem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Of course, you need all the vendor prefix *(-webkit-transform, -moz-transform)*.
This is [compatible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) with all majors browsers (IE9 and up)